# How to add several positions under the same company title in Awesome CV?

Tags: formatting

I am working on Awesome CV [Download Here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm).
I am trying to put several job positions under the same company (such as Scientist I.... Scientist II....). I'm not sure how to customize it.
Here is what I have in "experience.tex" page:

```
\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}

\cventry
{Scientist I} % Job title
{Ultragenyx} % Organization
{CA} % Location    
{June 2021 - August 2022} % Date(s)
{
    \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
     \item {Scientist does this and that.} 
    \end{cvitems}
  }
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

It would be great to have "Scientist II" under the same company name without having to create another cv entry.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: If I recall it correctly, you simply repeat the macro **\cventry{}{}{}{}{}** (it takes 5 parameters, i.e. text snippets). I don‘t remember a restriction as Elad mentions in the answer below, but assume it‘s there. So if you need more positions, use that solution.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the `\cventry` command defined in the awsome cv template, you can define a new command called `cventrydouble` (or whatever) that would get 8 inputs rather than the usual 5 and output them as you seek.

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}

\name{Claud D.}{Park}
\position{Software Architect{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}Security Expert}
\address{42-8, Bangbae-ro 15-gil, Seocho-gu, Seoul, 00681, Rep. of KOREA}

\mobile{(+82) 10-9030-1843}
\email{posquit0.bj@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.posquit0.com}
\github{posquit0}
\linkedin{posquit0}


\quote{``Be the change that you want to see in the world."}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\cventrydouble}[8]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
   \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
     \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\
       \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}\\
       \entrypositionstyle{#6} & \entrydatestyle{#7} \\
       \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#8}}}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\
      \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}\\
      \entrypositionstyle{#6} & \entrydatestyle{#7} \\
      \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#8}}
     }
   \end{tabular*}%
}
\makeatother

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvheader

\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {Claud D. Park~~~·~~~Curriculum Vitae}
  {\thepage}


\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\cventrydouble
{Scientist I} % Job title
{Ultragenyx} % Organization
{CA} % Location    
{June 2021 - August 2022} % Date(s)
{
    \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
     \item {Scientist does this and that.} 
    \end{cvitems}
  }
{Scientist II} % Job title
{August 2022 - August 2025} % Date(s)
{
    \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
     \item {Scientist does this and that.} 
    \end{cvitems}
  }
%---------------------------------------------------------
 \cventry
    {Freelance Penetration Tester} % Job title
    {SAMSUNG Electronics} % Organization
    {S.Korea} % Location
    {Sep. 2013, Mar. 2011 - Oct. 2011} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
        \item {Conducted penetration testing on SAMSUNG KNOX, which is solution for enterprise mobile security.}
        \item {Conducted penetration testing on SAMSUNG Smart TV.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
    
\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

Notice: If you want to make it more elegant, you can redefine the old `\cventry` to `\oldcventry` with `\let`, redefine the double entry as `\cventry` with `renewcommand` rather than with `newcommand` and have the new `cventry` call the old one in case inputs 6-8 are empty.